# export mysql data in excel file using php excel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am getting error while generating an excel file using PHPExcel from a query against mysql table
Fatal error: 'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation\Functions.php on line 574

my php code is

```
<?php
include 'connection.php'; 
require_once '../../../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$query =  "SELECT question_name FROM current_affairs_question_details where id='$_GET[currentaffairid]' limit 0,20";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$rowcount=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowcount, $row['question_name']);
    $rowcount++;
}
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('some_excel_file.xlsx');

?>
```

Comment: What version of PHPExcel are you running?

Comment: I am using PHPExcel version  1.7.8

Comment: Well perhaps update to a more recent version, like 1.8.1